# Concerning the Verbal "From"

Tags: preposition, grammar-identification

I am attempting to translate a text from english to latin, and am unsure how to translate the word from when it is used in the context of a verb. An example would be: "I took from him..."; another example would be "I learned many things from her." I know that one of the translations of *dē* is *from*, but was unsure if this is a specific class of usage.

Thank You.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're all different uses! Different verbs will have different constructions, and you cannot, as a rule, ever do a one-to-one correspondence based on English's idioms. Take "take away," for example.

You actually have a couple of options depending on the thing you're taking away. Some words add on *ex* to the beginning of a verbalized noun, like *exanimare* "to take the life away from [someone]" i.e. "to kill."

As a synonym for deprive, you have *orbare* (to take away parents/children/etc. from someone) or *spoliare* (to take spoils away from a conquered people). Others are *adimere* or *privare*, too!

The nouns associated with the verbs change, too. Some, like *privare*, have the item removed in the ablative and the person from which in the accusative. (Sort of like the way "strip" would work: You strip me of my possessions = You took my possessions from me.) *Eripere*, as another example, has the items taken away in accusative and the person from which they are taken be in ablative with the preposition *ex*. Caesar, for example, writes *ereptum* ***ex manibus*** *hostium* "taken away/snatched **from the hands** of the enemies.

Without knowing what you want to say, it will be difficult to say for sure how to say it in Latin.

Comment: Great answer. The first word that came to my mind for "take away" is "aliquid ab aliquo **auferre**."